# Tkinter GUI for R Scripts: How to streamline Tkinter file input into an R script to run on button click

Tags: r, tkinter

I am building a toolbox for bioinformatical analysis of DNA sequences. All the statistical analysis is done in R. I have written the R scripts for these.

I am now building a GUI with Tkinter so users can choose a file with DNA information and run my R scripts on them. I am at the very beginning of the Tkinter script and I am stuck on getting the information (directory path) the user selects into my R script, which is then executed on that file.

Here is the test code if you want to run the GUI yourself:

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
import tkFileDialog
import os
import sys
import subprocess

top = Tkinter.Tk()
CDR3Merge = "PHB_forR.R"

#####----------Definitions------------####

#Definition to open file browser and select file.
def FileOpen():
    var.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt"))

#Definition to start R-Script
def CDR3Extract():
    os.popen("R CMD BATCH PHB_forR.R").read()


####----------Buttons and their Functions-------------####

#Button to browse and open/select file
ButtonOpenFile = Tkinter.Button(top, text="Open File", command = FileOpen)
ButtonOpenFile.grid(row=1, column=1)

#Button to Execute R-Script
ButtonCDR3Extract = Tkinter.Button(top, text="CDR3 Extraction", command = CDR3Extract)
ButtonCDR3Extract.grid(row=2,column=0)

#####----------Entry Bars and their Definition--------####
#Label at the very top
TopLabel = Tkinter.Label(text="CDR3 Extraction")
TopLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)

#Entry for file selection
var = Tkinter.StringVar()
FileEntry = Tkinter.Entry(top, width=60, textvariable= var)
FileEntry.grid(row=1,column=0)


####---------------------------------------------------####

top.mainloop()
```

And Im guessing we need to focus on this part:

```
  #Definition to open file browser and select file.
def FileOpen():
    var.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt"))

#Definition to start R-Script
def CDR3Extract():
    os.popen("R CMD BATCH PHB_forR.R").read()
```

I don´t know if it is necessary to post my R script, but the method/code with which I read my .txt file in R is following:

```
read.delim("file.txt",header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

How can I turn the output of the askopenfile command from Tkinter into a variable used in my R script? Is this even possible or should I consider a different method of doing this?

Thank you.

*Edit*: After Dason recommended to check out commandArgs() in R I wanted to print the filepath together with the command to run the Rscript. So now the button CDR3 Extract will do folliwng:

```
def CDR3Extract():
        os.popen("Rscript PHB_forR.R" + " " + str(var).read()
```

var still being

```
var = Tkinter.SrtingVar()
```

The problem I am having now is that var is returned as PY_VAR0 instead of the filepath that is printed in my entry box.

I have tried `var.get()` and using that but it also returns as PY_VAR0.

Any suggestions? I am probably looking at this the wrong way I can´t find or come up with something more simple.

Comment: Check this out in R: `help(commandArgs)`

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm almost there, I have set up the R script to use as `commandArgs()` so when I execute `Rscript PHB_forR.R filename.R`it will use filename.R as the file to read. However, this does not seem to work with the file in a different directory as the script and neither have I been able to get the path of the file into the definition/command in my python script. I thought `os.popen("R CMD BATCH PHB_forR.R", var).read()`would do it, as var is the path directory, however I get a error message that says  TypeError: must be string, not instance"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so here is what works:

```
def CDR3Extract():
os.popen("Rscript test_forR.R" + " " + var.get()).read()
```

as `var`is set to return the file path selected by the user it had to be added as `var.get()`. This way it does not return as PY_VAR0 but as the path. To recap how `var`is set:

```
def FileOpen():
    var.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt"))
var = Tkinter.StringVar()
```

Running `Rscript script.R /path/to/file.txt`works, however, in order to get only the filepath when using `commandArgs()`I had to get rid of `script.R`in R, because `commandArgs()`would give me:

```
filepath <- commandArgs()
filepath
[1] script.R
[2] /path/to/file.txt
```

so I used

```
filepath2 <- filepath[-1]
filepath2
[1] /path/to/file.txt
```

The file can then be read in R with

```
read.delim(filepath2,header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

I hope I answered the question in a way outsiders can follow? Please let me know if I should go into more detail.

Thank you for your help.